# CNAME for root domain in Cpanel

Tags: dns, cpanel, cname, amazon-aws

I have a domain, let's say example.com Other parties are involved (they purchased the domain and gave me access only to the CPanel)

I am using AWS Amplify to host my frontend, and I have added the "www" CNAME in the DNS configuration.

Now [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is pointing to my AWS Amplify Frontend.

However, example.com is not. And DNS from CPanel doesn't support adding a CNAME to the root domain. (AWS Amplify doesn't give an IP address for me to use A Record)

I also added on the CPanel a redirection setting from example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but this did not work.

Any help? I know that cloudflare uses CNAME Flattening to support the root domain as a CNAME, but not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Top root domains don't use CNAME, you must create an A record for it. You can later point other subdomains, such as WWW as a CNAME to the root domain, or alternatively, an A record to the IP where the server is hosted.

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran the problem is that most AWS services (including amplify) don't support `A` records, they are behind a form of dynamic DNS where IP addresses change without notice.

Comment: what is @stephen-ostermiller saying is correct. They are behind a dynamic IP address (CDN)

Comment: From@StephenOstermiller note, I looked up the Amplify documentation, and found this: "For DNS providers that do not have ANAME/ALIAS support, we strongly recommend migrating your DNS to Amazon Route 53. " This might point you in the right direction: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran migrating to amazon route 53 was not a viable option in my case

Answer (score 2):

The domain apex can't use `CNAME` records period, not just in cPanel.  Modern DNS hosts now support `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records where you specify a host name that gets served as an `A` record. The system looks up the IP every few minutes to facilitate that.  As far as I know, cPanel doesn't support this, so you have to look for a non-DNS solution.

I would take the approach of pointing the domain apex to the cPanel hosting account.  Then you can use the cPanel hosting to issue the redirect to `www`. You can have cPanel get a free LetsEncrypt certificate so that `https://example.com/` works.   You would need to create a `.htaccess` file with the contents:

```sh
Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com
```

That way your web app is hosted on Amplify with a CNAME pointing to `www` and the domain apex is hosted in cPanel and just redirects to Amplify.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!